Showing $\lim\limits_{\theta \to 0^+}(\sin \theta)^{(\sin \theta-\sin^{2} \theta)} = 1$
So I recently came across this limits problem in a test and whatever I tried was in vain. For example, I tried expanding, taking natural logarithms, and raising to the power of $e$ but in vain. Can't figure it out.

Can you use Taylor expansion?

$= \lim_{\theta -> 0^+} e^{[\sin \theta - \sin^2 \theta] \ln \sin \theta}$.  So you need to show $\lim_{\theta -> 0^+}  [\sin \theta - \sin^2 \theta] \ln \sin \theta = 0$. So apply L'Hopital to $\dfrac{\ln \sin \theta}{1 / (\sin \theta - \sin^2 \theta)}$.

@Dave77 Correct. Didn't notice that. Thanks .

Indeed, I would say that the standard approach to indeterminate limits of functions of the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is to take logarithms (as in @Dave77's comment) and reduce it to an indeterminate product. (Here we're using the continuity of the logarithm and exponential functions.) Sometimes we see other ways which is great, but we should consider taking the logarithm the go-to tool whenever we're not sure how to proceed.

First remove $\sin$ everywhere (by composition of limits, since $\lim_{\theta\to0^+}\sin\theta=0^+$). Then, as $x\to0^+$, $\ln(x^{x-x^2})=(1-x)(x\ln x)\to(1-0)0=0$.

@AnneBauval +1: Composition of limits is a nice touch.

First remove $\sin$
everywhere (by composition of limits, since $\lim_{\theta\to0^+}\sin\theta=0^+$). Then, as $x→0^+$, $$\ln(x^{x-x^2})=(1-x)(x\ln x)\to(1-0)0=0.$$
The key point was
$$\lim_{x→0^+}x\ln x=0.$$

I'd like to give my contribution to what has already been said in the comments (since applying L'Hôpital's after simply taking the log would imply taking some very boring derivatives). First, let $\xi=\sin\theta$, so that $\xi\to0^+$ as $\theta\to0^+$.
The limit becomes:
$$\lim_{\xi\to0^+}\xi^{\xi(1-\xi)}$$
Which is way simpler. Now you can either notice that the exponent approaches $0$ faster than the base, so the limit is $1$, or do it in a more rigorous way, which is the one explained in the comments (but with way simpler functions):
$$\exp\left(\lim_{\xi\to0^+}\frac{\log\xi}{1/[\xi(1 - \xi)]}\right)$$
and apply L'Hôpital's rule.
